# Correctly highlight a square with transparent radial gradient

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients

I am trying to highlight a square with radial gradient effect. I created the following css rule:

```
.highlight-move {
    background-color: #75f547;
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, #75f547, #fff 100%);
    background-image:         radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, #75f547, #fff 100%);    
}
```

The problem is that my gradient is not transparent: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ek1u9kL2/) and therefore I have a white background on the square.

I thought that I would be able to fix it with rgba, but as you see in the fiddle it does not work. How can I make my gradient transparent?

One additional important problem is not to highlight the piece on that color: [thanks to Hashem for his :after solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/ek1u9kL2/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are overriding the background color of the square itself so that the `rgba()` won't give the desired effect in that case.

You could use pseudo-elements to apply the gradient on top of the square as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ek1u9kL2/3/)**

```css
.highlight-move:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; /* set dimensions up to the parent */

    background: #75f547;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, rgba(117, 245, 71, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background:         radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, rgba(117, 245, 71, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works amazing, but is there any other way to achieve this? The problem is that it also highlights the piece standing on that color: http://jsfiddle.net/ek1u9kL2/4/ . Sorry, I have not thought about it.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Yes there is. However you can fix that by adding a higher `z-index` to the pieces like so: `.highlight-move img { position: relative; z-index: 2; }`. **[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ek1u9kL2/5/)**

Comment: The other solution is creating two classes for two cases of cells having different background color. In each one, you have to change `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` with the background color of the cell. **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ek1u9kL2/7/)**